# How to avoid redirect if url match a string in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, lets-encrypt

I have a web server that redirects any HTML 404 error to another domain:

`ErrorDocument 404 https://error domain`

My goal if to avoid redirection when Let’s Encrypt tries to renew the certificates.

All Let’s Encrypt challenges starts with: `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`

I have tried this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https:// error domain
RewriteEngine on
Redirect "/.well-known/acme-challenge/" "/.well-known/acme-challenge/"
```

But I have the error "too many redirects" (and I understand why... :/).
It is important that Let’s Encrypt works without human interaction, temporary modify the vitualhost is forbidden, for this I need that when a uri starts with:

`/.well-known/acme-challenge/ ... etc` -> no redirection
`/anotherstring/ ect..` -> https://error domain

I am sure that this will solve my problem, because if I delete

`ErrorDocument 404 https://error domain`

then Let’s Encrypt renewal works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LocationMatch "!/\.well-known/acme-challenge/">
  ErrorDocument 404 https://error.domain
</LocationMatch>
```